# Cannot install UWP app from hockey app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, uwp, hockeyapp

I'm doing an app using Xamarin.Forms and I've already deployed the Android and iOS version to HockeyApp but I have a problem with the UWP (Windows 10 version)...

These are the steps I do:

- Right click on my UWP project
- Select "Store" option
- Select "Create app packages"
- A window pops and I select "No" and click "Next"
- Then I only select the ARM configuration
- Click "Next"

My package has been created and I drag n drop the .appxbundle file to hockeyapp.

Once the package is uploaded, I start my Windows 10 Mobile emulator and try to install it...
I download it from HockeyApp and when I install it, **nothing happens**...

Do you have any idea where this problem comes from?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: You have to associate your app with store by right clicking the **UWP Project-> Store-> Associate App With Store** (btw you don't need to have a Windows Store account for this process).

Comment: I did. Still the same

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 mobile emulator not supported ARM, only x86/x64. You need the real device for test ARM package.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing exactly the same, but I've managed to fix it. Here's what I've done:

1. I **associated the app with Store** in Visual Studio
2. I installed **Windows 10 Mobile Anniversary update** (OS Build: 10.0.14383.953), since my app was targeting Anniversary Update.
3. I installed **the certificate** which was included in the .ZIP file next to the .appxbudnle

Then I run the .appxbundle and clicked install. The installer exited without any message, just like before, but after a minute or so the app appeared in the installed apps on my Microsoft Lumia 650.